# Triple Head Nvidia and Intel

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have a [dell inspiron](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/inspd530/en/OM/HTML/appendix.htm) with an Intel integrated video and an nvidia video card. actually i have a dual head 2 x 27 samsungs monitors and i got an old 24 inch sitting there by himself crying to be plugged.

i would like to know if it's possible to do have a triple head with my computer and if so, how can i do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes its possible, look at this one:

http://wn.com/6_Monitor_Linux_workstation_using_Ubuntu_and_Compiz

this guy use 6 monitors, so 3 its possible

now, here's a config i found : https://superuser.com/questions/132290/triple-monitor-setup-in-linux

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 1.0  (buildd@crested)  Sun Feb  1 20:25:37 UTC 2009
# edited by me (brendan) 2010-04-18


#   NVIDIA magic (something about glx-new?)
Section "Module"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection



#   Keyboards and Mice
Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection




#   Physical Monitors:
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Acer"
    ModelName      "Acer H233H"
    HorizSync       40.0 - 70.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Acer"
    ModelName      "Acer AL2216W"
    HorizSync       40.0 - 70.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "BenQ"
    ModelName      "BenQ W500"
    HorizSync       44.955 - 45.0
    VertRefresh     59.94 - 60.0
EndSection




#   Physical Video Cards/Ports:
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GTX+"
#    Screen          0
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

#Section "Device"
#    Identifier     "Device1"
#    Driver         "nvidia"
#    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
#    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GTX+"
#    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
#    Screen         1
#EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Device2"
    Driver        "nvidia"
    VendorName    "nVidia Corporation"
    BoardName     "GeForce 7900 GT/GTO"
    BusID         "PCI:4:0:0"
    Option        "TVStandard" "HD720p"
EndSection




####    Default 3-monitor Layout 'default'

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen2" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection


#   Virtual Screens
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
#    Option         "NoTwinViewXineramaInfo"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1080 +1680+0, DFP-1: 1680x1050 +0+30"
#    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1080 +1680+0, DFP-1: 1680x1050 +0+15; DFP-0: NULL, DFP-1: 1680x1050 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

#Section "Screen"
#    Identifier     "Screen0"
#    Device         "Device0"
#    Monitor        "Monitor0"
#    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "TwinView" "0"
#    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080"
#    SubSection     "Display"
#        Depth       24
#    EndSubSection
#EndSection

#Section "Screen"
#    Identifier     "Screen1"
#    Device         "Device1"
#    Monitor        "Monitor1"
#    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "TwinView" "0"
#    Option         "metamodes" "1680x1050"
#    SubSection     "Display"
#        Depth       24
#    EndSubSection
#EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1280x720"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Of course you will have to modify it but that will help you to see how ti works**

found another tread about it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1502753

another one: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811366

Comment: In this configuration, all seems to be nvidia cards - so is this really the same? Can the X server load two different drivers?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to make it work so that you are actually using a single session on all three. There is work being done on kernel & Xorg upstream to make it possible, though. It'll still take quite some time to get it in shape, and included in a release.

EDIT: meh, forgot about xinerama, see for instance [Triple-head on a Lenovo T520](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71341/triple-head-on-a-lenovo-t520) for instructions about setting it up. Note that you won't get 3D on the intel though, if you use nvidia's driver.

Comment: really? Can you supply details on this? I find it hard to believe that it's impossible to do 4+ monitors (on session) in Linux. What's preventing it in this case?