# T420 DisplayPort

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Triple-head on a Lenovo T520](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71341/triple-head-on-a-lenovo-t520)

I've got a Thinkpad T420.  I want to know if it's possible to get three displays running at once (laptop + vga + displayport)?  Has anyone achieved this?

Longer ramble follows:

I'm not concerned with power management.  I'm happy to use Discret graphics in the BIOS, but after much messing about I've not got Optimus and Bumblebee working otherwise, and when I try and reboot and switch to Discrete graphics in the BIOS I just get a blank screen when I boot (presumably as the nvidia drivers aren't installed?).

This post, http://zachstechnotes.blogspot.com/2012/01/tri-head-display-on-linux-thinkpad-w520.html, claims that the 520 can only output to 2 of 3 displays at once, but says "It seems that on the T420 and T520, the integrated card is also connected to the VGA output, but I have no way of verifying this".

As an aside, I understand that DisplayPort isn't a Bumblebee feature just now, despite some claiming it works.  I've tried to follow the instructions here, https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/77 and if I run

```
optirun -d :8.0 glxspheres
```

The standby light on my monitor lights up as if it's about to come on, but then the glxspheres runs on the laptop display.

If I try other settings for -d they call say "could not open display".

So there's two different things here, either getting three outputs using the discrete card in the BIOS, or getting it to work with Bumblebee.  Any ideas?  Maybe I should just sit tight until Bumblebee can do it.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate?  The other question is about a 520, and my laptop is a 420.  The blog post I linked to claims that a 520 can only output to 2 of 3 displays but speculates that this may be different on the 420.  How can that possibly be an exact duplicate?