# Can't load x.org nvidia driver when intel gpu is enabled (3 monitor setup)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, intel

I'm trying to build a 3 monitor setup using 2 nvidia DVI outputs and 1 intel VGA onboard output. I have this weird issue that when I enable my onboard intel vga out I can't load the nvidia x.org module anymore:

```
[   363.899] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[   363.899] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[   363.899] (II) Unloading nvidia
[   363.899] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

When I disable the onboard intel VGA ouput my Nvidia module loads fine. I have all nvidia packages installed, and the kernel modules are correctly compiled and the nvidia kernel module is loaded.

I've tried many config settings, but I always have the same problem, I just can't use my Nvidia card somehow when this onboard intel gpu is enabled. I think this x.org layout config is very similar to what I try to accomplish:
[Triple-head on a Lenovo T520](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71341/triple-head-on-a-lenovo-t520)

Using this config (only changing the busid) the result is that I only have a working desktop on my intel output when the intel gpu is enabled, and only desktop on my nvidia screens when intel gpu is disabled.

In both cases the nvidia card is listen when `lspci` is used. When I use `jockey-text -l` while Intel GPU is enabled I get nothing, while disabled I get `xorg:nvidia_current` and `xorg:nvidia_current_updates`.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Do they both show up in `lspci` output? Since the same config works when one of the gpus is disabled, I don't trust the error message.

You could try fixing the interrupt and memory apertures in BIOS.

Comment: Yes they both show up with `lspci` when I enable the onboard intel gpu.